# Can I use a toroidal inductor as part of a tuning circuit for medium waves?

Tags: rf, analog, electromagnetism, radio

Toroidal inductors can have very high inductances. So is it possible use a toroid as the tuning coil for a AM radio? If so, what are the drawbacks?

Comment: In fact inductors hand-wound on powdered-metal torroids are the norm for hand built amateur radio gear on the lower HF bands, which has far tougher technical requirements than an AM broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main drawback is that you'll need a separate antenna.

The usual ferrite rod, being open ended, picks up RF radiation pretty well, so it acts as both the inductor in a tuning circuit and the antenna.

A toroid, being a closed magnetic circuit, won't, so without another antenna you won't pick up much signal.

Answer (score 3):

A toroidal inductor generally doesn't have a gap in the core and this certainly does increase the inductance for a given number of turns. However, for most commonly used ferrite core materials this will mean that temperature changes will change the permeability of the core and the inductance will rise or fall. This of course means tuning will or can drift. Here are a couple of common materials from ferroxcube: -

[image]

A gap significantly lowers the effective permeability of the core and this also significantly reduces the temperature dependency. You also have to find a core that is suitable for AM radio frequencies (about 1 MHz) and this is by no means a given for every core material: -

[image]

So what you want is a material that remains fairly flat across the band you want to operate in.

Comment: Nonetheless, inductors hand-wound on carefully selected torroidal cores are the norm in hand-built ham gear for the HF bands, which tends to need far higher short-term frequency stability than broadcast receivers.  It is rarer there though for a tuned circuit to be used as a frequency standard, rather it is usually tuned in operation to some other standard or simply as needed.  It's unlikely anyone expects their AM tuning dial to be particularly accurate either.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - "carefully selected" cores are the important thing and toroids are usually the preferred choice as baluns. Re temperature dependence; I'm thinking that if you tune in to a station then as the radio warms it will annoyingly drift off - this to me is the major issue i.e. one of inconvenience.

Comment: Not just ferrite torrodial transformers and baluns, powdered metal Amidon #2 and #6 etc are pretty much the preferred DIY inductor in tuned circuits in such hand-built rigs.  Perhaps remember that simple solid state radios don't "warm up" that much.  With a typical ham receiver circuit you'd readily hear pulling from moving your hand near a parallel plate tuning capacitor if it were left unshielded, something that is a essentially a non-issue with AM broadcast.  So if there were a serious real-world problem, it would show up in the ham usage more than in what the poster wants to do.